# sorting lines of an enormous file.txt in java

Tags: java, sorting, text-files, lines

I'm working with a very big text file (755Mb).
I need to sort the lines (about 1890000) and then write them back in another file.

I already noticed that discussion that has a starting file really similar to mine:
[Sorting Lines Based on words in them as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572762/sorting-lines-based-on-words-in-them-as-keys)

The problem is that i cannot store the lines in a collection in memory because I get a Java Heap Space Exception (even if i expanded it at maximum)..(already tried!)

I can't either open it with excel and use the sorting feature because the file is too large and it cannot be completely loaded..

I thought about using a DB ..but i think that writing all the lines then use the SELECT query it's too much long in terms of time executing..am I wrong?

Any hints appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, "too long" depends on your expectations. If you hope doing it in half a second, it'll indeed be too long. If you don't mind waiting for a few seconds or minutes, it shouldn't be a problem. Try it, and see if the time is reasonable.

Comment: You should be able to store the file in memory with about 1 GB of heap using the latest versions of Java. i.e. with `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the solution here is to do a merge sort using temporary files:

1. Read the first *n* lines of the first file, (*n* being the number of lines you can afford to store and sort in memory), sort them, and write them to file `1.tmp` (or however you call it). Do the same with the next *n* lines and store it in `2.tmp`. Repeat until all lines of the original file has been processed.
2. Read the first line of each temporary file. Determine the smallest one (according to your sort order), write it to the destination file, and read the next line from the corresponding temporary file. Repeat until all lines have been processed.
3. Delete all the temporary files.

This works with arbitrary large files, as long as you have enough disk space.

Comment: I fully agree.  It can be done using the 'mergesort' algorithm

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following with

```
-mx1g -XX:+UseCompressedStrings  # on Java 6 update 29
-mx1800m -XX:-UseCompressedStrings  # on Java 6 update 29
-mx2g  # on Java 7 update 2.
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        generateFile("lines.txt", 755 * 1024 * 1024, 189000);

        List<String> lines = loadLines("lines.txt");

        System.out.println("Sorting file");
        Collections.sort(lines);
        System.out.println("... Sorted file");
        // save lines.
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f second to read, sort and write to a file%n", time / 1e9);
    }

    private static void generateFile(String fileName, int size, int lines) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Creating file to load");
        int lineSize = size / lines;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sb.length() < lineSize) sb.append('-');
        String padding = sb.toString();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            String text = (i + padding).substring(0, lineSize);
            pw.println(text);
        }
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("... Created file to load");
    }

    private static List<String> loadLines(String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Reading file");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            ret.add(line);
        System.out.println("... Read file.");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Creating file to load
... Created file to load
Reading file
... Read file.
Sorting file
... Sorted file
Took 4.886 second to read, sort and write to a file
```

Comment: Can you repeat the test using jdk7u2 to see how much memory and time it takes?

Comment: Unfortunately Java 7 doesn't support this option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833385/is-support-for-compressed-strings-being-dropped

Comment: Yep, but would still like to see how much memory it uses without the option. Maybe they have made improvements such that this option is no longer required.

Comment: @dogbane A reasonable question, Java 7 needs 200 MB more than Java 6 with compressed Strings off. :]

Answer (score 1):

[divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) is the best solution :)

divide your file to smaller ones, sort each file seperately then regroup.

Links:

[Sort a file with huge volume of data given memory constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087469/sort-a-file-with-huge-volume-of-data-given-memory-constraint)

http://hackerne.ws/item?id=1603381

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

How much memory do we have available? Let’s assume we have `X MB` of memory available.

1. Divide the file into `K` chunks, where `X * K = 2 GB`. Bring each chunk into memory and sort the lines as usual using any `O(n log n)` algorithm. Save the lines back to the file.
2. Now bring the next chunk into memory and sort.
3. Once we’re done, merge them one by one.

The above algorithm is also known as external sort. Step 3 is known as **N-way merge**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try multithreading and increasing heap size of the program you are running? (this also requires you to use merge sort kind of thing provided you have more memory than 755mb in your system.)

Comment: See comment left for Eric.Sun above.

Comment: Yes, your reason is obviously useful in very very large filesize. But the OP specified file size to be 755mb and most of the computers today have more than 755mb. Why use a complex algorithm if we can solve his/her problem with just -Xmx1024m?

Comment: Merge sort is not a overly complex algorithm.  I did not want to make assumptions on the hardware used by the algorithm.  Also, the process may not be the only software running on the device.  In my humble opinion writing a 50 lines of code to save more than a GB of memory (each line may take up several bytes, if it is string) is well worth the effort.  (No offense intended.)

Comment: No, I agree with you whatsoever. If I was in the similar scenario, I'd have just tried increasing the heap size first. If that didn't work, I'd have probably done what you've suggested. Its all good :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Let's compromise on both solutions,  i.e., try the memory approach and log a ticket to replace it with the more memory-efficient approach (with accompanied test cases) at a later stage (+1).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe u can use perl to format the file .and load into the database like mysql. it's so fast. and use the index to query the data. and write to another file.

u can set jvm heap size like '-Xms256m -Xmx1024m' .i hope to help u .thanks

Comment: Using a file-based merge sort is much better than simply allocating more memory.  What happens if the file gets even bigger, i.e. 10gigs?